# manipulate a column based on another column

Tags: r

My data looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dea36ef7b86f71120d50

At first I load the data like below

```
df <- read.delim(".../sample.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE, row.names=1)
```

then I will only keep the columns that I want like below

```
dfm<- df[,c(match(c('m'), colnames(df)),
               unlist(lapply(c("mm"), 
                          function(x) grep(x, colnames(df)))))]
```

**As an example** the first two column of **dfm** looks like this

```
row.names                                                   
CON__A2A4G1                                                          0.880950
CON__A2A5Y0                                                          0.034051
CON__A2AB72                                                          0.079625
CON__ENSEMBL                                     NaN
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024146                                      0.133800
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024466;CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024462      0.288080
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000025008                                       NaN
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000038253                                      0.101990
sp|O43790|KRT86_HUMAN;CON__O43790                                    0.970460
sp|O76009|KT33A_HUMAN;CON__O76009;CON__Q6NTB9                        0.521410
```

I want to create another data frame or matrix or ... that the column names are the same as the df.
then check the second column, if it has value , then paste the name of the first column there, if it is NA or empty, write NA or nothing
the same for the third column and fourth ... until the end

the example output (just for the second column) looks like this.

```
CON__A2A4G1                                                          
CON__A2A5Y0                                                         
CON__A2AB72                                                         
**Nothing**                                       
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024146                                      
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024466;CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000024462      
**Nothing**                                       
CON__ENSEMBL:ENSBTAP00000038253
```

Comment: Hint: `ifelse(is.na(dat$columnIwanttocheck), "",rownames(dat))`

Comment: @Heroka thank I tried to use this but I could not use it with apply to perform it on the entire data.

Comment: And you really want to keep the rows with missing values? If not, you could use something like `complete.cases`. Otherwise, if Heroka's solution does not work, try using `apply(your_data, 1, function(x) any(is.na(x))` to get an index of the rows that you want to fill with `**Nothing**`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 df <- read.delim("example.txt", header=TRUE, sep="\t", fill=TRUE, row.names=1,  stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings='')
 df[] <- lapply(df, as.numeric)

 dfm<- df[,c(match(c('Ratio.H.L.normalized'), colnames(df)),
        unlist(lapply(c("Ratio.H.L.normalized.Mo"), 
                      function(x) grep(x, colnames(df)))))]

 dfm[] <- lapply(dfm, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), "", rownames(dfm)) )
```

First, I replace all strings "NA" with actual `NA`s. Make sure that all values are supposed to be either numeric or missing, otherwise this is a critical thing to do. Then, along all columns, I replace the value with the rowname whenever the value is missing.

Note 1: I wonder in which circumstance the above procedure is useful, and just in case your description was a bit off and you actually only want to keep the rows where all values are non-missing, have a look at `?complete.cases`.

Note 2: Your way of extracting the columns from your bigger dataset appears somewhat complicated to me. I am sure it is correct, but you could also try something along the following lines:

```
library(dplyr)
dfm <- select(df, contains("Ratio.H.L.normalized"))
```

This should give the same result but is much easier to read.

Edit: adressed misunderstanding about desired solution and switched `ifelse`-statement around to reflect comment.

Edit 2: a potentially easier solution would be the following:

```
 name_mat <- matrix(rep(rownames(dfm), ncol(dfm)), ncol=ncol(dfm), nrow =  length(rownames(dfm)))
 dfm_ind <- is.na(dfm)

 name_mat[!dfm_ind] <- NA
```

First I create a big matrix that contains all your rownames that has the same dimensions as the initial `dfm` dataframe. Then I create an index which tells me which of the entries in the `dfm` dataframe are missing. Then I use that index to replace the values in the matrix of repeated rownames. If need be, you can change the column names with the `names()` or `colnames()` functions, to harmonize the column names as well.

Comment: thanks the solution you gave is opposite to what i was looking for . I dont want to replace NA with the name of rows names . Please look at the output I showed above in my question

Comment: This is the answer. dfm[] <- lapply(dfm, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x)," ",rownames(dfm)))   do you know if we can do it with any other way ?

Comment: Yes, in `R`, you can do everything in multiple ways. But why would you want to deviate from this approach? That information would help understand how a solution should look like. Otherwise, if this solves your problem, please accept the answer so that other people can see that the issue has been resolved.